# How to show error message in OutlinedTextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I need to show error message in `OutlinedTextField` and I don't find any documentation about how to do it. I found several ways in tutorials, for example to create custom input field with hint or create `Text` just below input field, but they very old and maybe there is a better way. I need show error message like this:

[image]

Code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EmailInputField(value: MutableState<String>, state: AuthState) {

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value.value,
        onValueChange = { value.value = it },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f).height(60.dp),
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White),
        label = { Text(text = "Email", color = Color.White) },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = blue,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.White
        ),
        isError = state is AuthState.ValidationError,
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With **M3** you can use the the **`supportingText`** attribute that is the optional supporting text to be displayed below the text field.

```
    val errorMessage = "Text input too long"
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var isError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val charLimit = 10

    fun validate(text: String) {
        isError = text.length > charLimit
    }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            validate(text)
        },
        singleLine = true,
        isError = isError,
        supportingText = {
            if (isError) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Limit: ${text.length}/$charLimit",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                )
            }
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isError)
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Error,"error", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error)
        },
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions { validate(text) },
    )
```

[image]

---

The **M2** `TextField` components doesn't support an `errorMessage` field.

You can easily achieve it using something like:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var isError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

fun validate(text: String) {
    isError = /* .... */
}

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            isError = false
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isError)
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Error,"error", tint = MaterialTheme.colors.error)
        },
        singleLine = true,
        isError = isError,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions { validate(text) },
    )
    if (isError) {
        Text(
            text = "Error message",
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The issue here is about `BringIntoViewRequester`. TextField manage its own `BringIntoViewRequester`, when the position is covered by keyboard, it will bring it self up to prevent covered. Unless we manage the error text focus requester, user can't see it when `BringIntoViewRequester` of TextField invoked.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Error icon anymore, Icons.Filled.Warning is the closest one

Answer (score 12):

#### Update

In Jetpack Compose Material 3 version `1.0.0` (released on October 24, 2022), we can use the `supportingText` attribute in the [OutlinedTextField](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors))

**Pics from Docs**
[image: Screenshots]

`supportingText` takes a Composable.

---

**Reference**
[Compose Material 3 Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#version_10_2)

Comment: I'm confused. I see the screenshot, I read the docu but an `OutlinedTextField` has no parameter "Supporting text" What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a ready to use composable that you can copy paste into your code. It has a `String` field called `error`that will display the error whenever it is not empty (that way you only have one state variable to keep track of). It is a bit verbose so you are able to customize it as you would any `OutlinedTextField`.

[image]

sample usage

```
OutlinedTextFieldValidation(
        value = studentState.firstName.value,
        onValueChange = { onFirstNameChange(it) },
        label = { Text(text = "First name") },
        error = "field cannot be empty"
    )
```

code to copy:

```
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldValidation(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    error: String = "",
    isError: Boolean = error.isNotEmpty(),
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = {
        if (error.isNotEmpty())
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Error, "error", tint = MaterialTheme.colors.error)
    },
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = Color.Black
    )

) {

    Column(modifier = modifier
        .padding(8.dp)) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            enabled = enabled,
            readOnly = readOnly,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            singleLine = singleLine,
            textStyle = textStyle,
            label = label,
            placeholder = placeholder,
            leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
            isError = isError,
            visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
            maxLines = maxLines,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            shape = shape,
            colors = colors
        )
        if (error.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 0.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working in `OutlinedTextField`. Causing problems like `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` and `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`. How can I resolve this? Please help!!

Comment: @gaurav make sure you added the composable fun to your code base and rememver you need to call the OutlinedTextFieldValidation from a function anotated as [@Composable}

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for @Gabriele Mariotti's solution that works with latest Compose and Material3:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var isError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

fun validate(text: String) {
    isError = /* .... */
}

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            isError = false
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isError)
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Info, "Error", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error)
        },
        singleLine = true,
        isError = isError,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions { validate(text) },
    )
    if (isError) {
        Text(
            text = "Error message",
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image: error sample]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`. and `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function` you can do like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyCustomTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    supportingText: String?,
    isError: Boolean
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        supportingText = supportingText?.let {
            @Composable {
                Text(
                    text = supportingText,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
                )
            }
        },
        isError = isError
    )
}
```